How to clean ubuntu of residual program files?
Ubuntu 22.04.
It seems simple, but I haven't found an answer on the internet.
I uninstalled 2 programs:
sudo apt purge chrome-browser
sudo apt purge gkellm

Then i used sudo apt autoremove.
But after I installed chrome and gkellm again, I saw that all the settings, cache and other program files were still there.
So in chrome the cache, cookies and open tabs were preserved.
In gkellm all the settings I used were saved.
How can I uninstall a program completely, including its configuration, cache and other files?
How do I clear the system of such files if I don't remember the package name? I have installed and uninstalled many programs and each one left garbage in my computer.

This question is similar to: How can you completely remove a package?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I saw this post yesterday. I tried using the tips from it. But as I wrote above, the configuration and temp files are still in my computer.
You did not read my question carefully.

Did you read the most upvoted answer carefully, particularly "It does not remove the configuration files and directories located in users' home directories (or in the .config subdirectory of their home directories), created by the software the package provides."  Did you delete the google-chrome folder inside the /home/newlinuxuser/.config/? I read your question. It does not say anything about .config folder.

You didn't understand the question and put a minus. It shows you to be incompetent. Just read the answers below and you will understand.

Try this:
At $  type man apt hit Enter then type /purge and hit Enter again.
you will see...

Removing a package removes all packaged data, but leaves usually small (modified) user configuration files behind, in case the
remove was an accident. Just issuing
an installation request for the accidentally removed package will restore its function as before in that case. On the other
hand you can get rid of these leftovers
by calling purge even on already removed packages. Note that this does not affect any data or configuration stored in
your home directory.


This indeed will work for system files, but is not applicable to the current question: user config data and cache (in this case of a browser). These are never automatically removed, but have to be manually removed.

Then that needs to be mentioned in the above text, bugger keeping secrets! 8-7 --- I'd call that a documentation fault.

it is actually included in the text you quoted. Last line.

Not clear enough; e.g. make it a separate paragraph.

When installing applications, system configuration files can be installed. Whenever you run a program for the first time, local user configuration files are created.

System configuration files are not removed when you apt remove an application. However, apt purge will not only remove the program files, but also the system configuration installed with that program. (The apt-purge command also can be used for already removed packages).

local user configuration is never automatically removed.


Thus, in order to delete your cache, cookies and settings, you need to manually remove the user configuration data left in your home folder. This user configuration data lives under hidden folders, or in hidden files in your user home directory.

Hidden files and folders have a file name that begins with a dot (.)

To show hidden files in the file manager, select the appropriate option. In many file managers, you can also hit Ctrl+H to toggle the display of hidden files.


In particular, configuration data commonly is stored under the folder .config in your home directory (~/.config). For example, user configuration data for Chrome is stored in ~/.config/google-chrome. Very commonly, applications store configuration data in their own hidden folder, e.g. ~/.dropbox or .mozilla.

Thank you. I got it.
I thought linux could do anything. I am new to this system. isn't there a command for terminal that will remove all unnecessary user configs, cache and other temporary files from programs I have uninstalled?

If this answer resolved your question, then please show your appreciation by "accepting" it: click the checkmark next to the answer. Although the answer may disappoint you, it is the correct answer: you need to remove left-over data in the home directory manually.

Isn't there any way to do this automatically through the terminal? I don't know how to do this manually. I don't even remember what programs I installed, because I try to install different packages, and if I don't like them, I uninstall them.

You can do a mass cleanup and purge all hidden files in your home directory, but then you will loose all custom configuration and possibly also data such as saved mails.
